# How to join two jQuery element objects? .add() isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm inside a function and I need to return a jQuery object with two elements. Inside the function I have, for example:

```
function getInput() {
    $hiddenInput = $('<input type="hidden">');
    //(other code)
    $select = $('<select></select>');
    //(other code)
    $hiddenInput.add($select);
    return $hiddenInput;
}
```

And outside I have:

```
$myContainer.append(getInput());
```

The result expected would be:

```
<div id="container"><input type="hidden"><select></select></div>
```

But the only thing I get right now with .add() is only the input element and not the select. How can I joint those two form elements on the function return? If not possible with jQuery, then with plain JavaScript. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) creates (and returns) a new jQuery object that is the union of the original set and what you're adding to it, but you're still returning the original in your function. You seem to have wanted to do this instead:

```
function getInput() {
    $hiddenInput = $('<input type="hidden">');
    //(other code)
    $select = $('<select></select>');
    //(other code)
    return $hiddenInput.add($select);
}
```

Comment: Oh my, that's in the docs. I had not read well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jquery documentation says the sort order is undefined in this case.

Comment: in short, we say `.add()` is *non-destructive*

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$hiddenInput.after($select);
```

That will put the `$select` after the `$hiddenInput`, achieving what you want to get.

Comment: Conversely you could use: `$select.insertAfter($hiddenInput);`

Comment: That didn't worked either. I only get the input element without the select, like with add().

Comment: It may be that none of the elements is in the DOM yet?

Comment: You're still returning `$hiddenInput` afterwards, yes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
this.MergejQueryObjects = function(arrayOfJqueryObjects) {
        return $($.map(arrayOfJqueryObjects, function (el) {
            return el.get();
        }));
    }
```